# jmeter not opened and showing executable file like as pdf

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am not able to open jmeter in my vm. exicutable file is showing like ApacheJMeter.jar and open as PDF.
Please some one help me on this where i did wrong.
Java(JDK) installed 8 verion updates.

Answer (score 0):

If in windows, open command prompt,

move to bin folder

```
cd <JMeterPAth>\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\
```

type

```
jmeter.bat
```

hope this should work.